# Comparing two images: get the XY location of any differences found

Tags: image-manipulation, imagemagick

I'm trying to compare two images using the ImageMagick Compare module; everything seems okay, but I want to know the exact XY locations of the 'differences' found. How can I get this?

I already checked Google but I can't seem to come up with a relevant keyword.

If it's not possible using the ImageMagick Compare module, any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: the resulting image of the compare module is enough for the user to see the difference, i need the XY location to zoom into the area once the user clicks on the list of XY locations

Comment: More likely the difference will not be a single pixel, but a region. You'd probably want to get the boundary of this region and then zoom to the centre of it. Not sure *how* you'd do that though, might be better asked on http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: We need a better process for deciding where to put questions. If you programmatic help, please add a  recognizable tag, like C#, or .net, or something that tells us what language you are using. This is like getting bounced around in those operatorless phone menu systems before finally getting the operator.

Comment: i was expecting that someone may have used imagemagick compare module and that i missed some points where i can enter some parameters when running the module, after that i will further manipulate the output using either lisp or C program module to further manipulate the data. thanks